# Can we avoid putting ad unit id in xml layout and rather put in activity class

Tags: android, admob

I want put all my ad unit ids at one place and use from that place in all the activities. I don't want to put unit ids in xml layout.

Comment: Yes you can use in string.xml as well in the activity.

Comment: You can create a constant class declare static strings with ad id there and then just use them wherever needed

Comment: If you put in a constant class.. you cannot access them in xml...

Comment: @Harshid do you think accessing string resource in java class is a good idea.....context.getString(R.string.COOL_STRING)

Comment: @priyanka178 Yes it's fine. If you want to used unit id from string class then you have to write admob code in activity class instead of XML,that's a good way.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a seperate Class and add String variables separate for Banner, Interstitial and Native Ad ids, whatever you require and you can easily reference them with

**Class Code**

```
public class AdmobClass {
    public String bannerId = "YOUR_BANNER_ID";
    public String interstitialId = "YOUR_INTERSTITIAL_ID";
    public String nativeId = "YOUR_NATIVE_ID";
```

}

**Call example**

```
String bannerId = new AdmobClass().bannerId;
```

Answer (score 0):

Better use **constants** that can't be changed during use:

```
public class AdmobClass {
    public static final String bannerId = "YOUR_BANNER_ID";
    public static final String interstitialId = "YOUR_INTERSTITIAL_ID";
    public static final String nativeId = "YOUR_NATIVE_ID";
}
```

And access from everywhere with:

```
String bannerId = AdmobClass.bannerId;
```